# how to show span's title in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

i have a span as:

```
<span class="word_span" title="ABC">abc</span>
```

for IOs access and convenient display, i'd like to show span's title when click, in JQuery:

```
  $(".word_span ").live("click", function (){
     ...;
  });
```

how to implement it?

Comment: which jquery version are you using ... coz live is deprecated in latest version ... instead use 'on'

Answer (score 7):

Try to retrieve the title attribute by using `.attr()` function,

```
 $(".word_span").live("click", function (){
    console.log($(this).attr('title'));
 });
```

**Side Notes:**  You are using `.live()` and it was removed in recent jquery versions so probably i would suggest you to use .on in this context,

```
 $(document).on("click",".word_span", function (){
    console.log($(this).attr('title'));
 });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/R3MXc/)

Comment: thx, i'd like to show up the title for end user. so what's the calling function?

Comment: In what means you want to display them to the user.?

Comment: @whi so you want to display them in a separate span or something..?

Comment: no, just want the span title pop up, like tool tip text.

Comment: @whi Can you visualize the thing that you have in your mind..? i could not able to get you..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55882/discussion-between-whi-and-rajaprabhu-aravindasamy).

Comment: @whi sorry in my office chat is disabled.. :(

Comment: sorry i just notice. When mouse hover on a span, the title will show up as tooltip text. I'd like to trigger it in click event.

Comment: thx @Raj, i have many this words in text. so i modify like http://jsfiddle.net/7VdW9/2/, it's a candidate solution. But is it possible just use span's title event, which is more convenient?

Comment: @whi Sorry as far as i know, there is no methods available to invoke the natural tool tip event manually..! But in our projects especially on touch devices we are preferring this kind of solutions only, what we have to do is position the tool tip based on the clicked element's  position..

Answer (score 1):

use .on click

because `.live` will work for *jQuery 1.3+*, `.on`  *jQuery 1.7+*

try this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script> 
$(function () { 
    $(".word_span ").on("click", function (){
       alert($(this).attr('title')); 
    });  
});  
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h6aRL/